# Remove "Unverified Server" Pop-up in StageWebView - Air for Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm developing an Android app using AIR SDK 21 & Adobe Air For Android. In the app I am using the AS3 StageWebView class to display web content to our users. What I am running into is that certain websites prompt the user with the following message in a pop up:

> "**The server that the application is connecting to is unverified**"
>   "Certificate: ,etc"
>  `"Trust for Session`, `Cancel"`

I am assuming this is a https/certificate issue, is there any way to remove this popup or instruct the app to just accept the connection?

Any help would be appreciated as this is happening on multiple sites and making the user experience unpleasant.

Thanks

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: This indicates one of three things (and the SDK has no way to decide which one):  1.  The server is misconfigured 2. The device doesn't trust the root certificate that signed the server's certificate 3.  Someone is trying to hack you.  For security reasons, turning this off is a Really Bad Idea.

Comment: Hey Brian, Thanks for responding. The thing I don't understand is that this popup happens even on some reputable sites. I uploaded a screen shot while visiting techcrunch.com from stageWebView on my Air for Android App. If I visit techcrunch.com on the same device from chrome it doesn't display this message. So does this indicate a problem on the AIR SDK end? If so, any idea how to troubleshoot? Thanks

Comment: Strange.  You're getting the cert for b-aws.aol.com instead of techcrunch.com.  That shouldn't be happening.